# Snailfence: Deciphering puzzle

Tags: cipher

The following text describes the method used to encipher it.

> Ssatnntloe-lree-itgaiima-t-odto-tl,hchaenisoa-a-oitnpsnefenf-p-coigtlxilon--letdnrhitC-iar-ae-reamralcppi-pttfp-dpt-ehrneWeaet-oet-nscewee-lgoeeuehbihrt--aescne-hroftia---lxeee.nnieanhbrh-sta-aca-mde-etce-oefn-nniarfeestt-x-p.sptl-prttoomto--it*-tfngi-dnn-rt-gh-rm-hrrdcap-io-t--.f-,ote--pa-ixi-niiilet-r,iAonns-w-o,scn-etoltoeierhWo-mtot-obwsfcefmndoeng-tntivtoiwl-ti.itofT-rreohere-mtr-te-dwaefhB-eoieohrosndtunt-gcnaetgol.hv--hdr-aielftxffd-lei-rh-otl-gewlrtlntocwa--eioh-eehn-hr-seoOxe-o.nfa---t-tatacsf.tPrr-tigoo-i-d-m-e-us-v-cwr.-,nt-anrmni-tmt--tete-n,eh-t-o-d.-iWhrirwtoe-f-Arhsiaotari-s-o*hlo--crcx-fetehhtdm-renia-Ci-tx-e-n--snhWol--tehdmheidAwmi-ctiPnetieremsdteioua--io-ehwIs,t-m-dtr-t--e.mddtd-e-t-footwaet-i-aptilpu---rwlnnr-ntpo-nr-spotnhit-lsftui--i,-tigtrvihercrgtmhrg-tmudcWnodeossyoatiwrlrhoefoerthswtrnslfne-ese-neoeh-ehoy-sni--c-hw.s-ofriafec-te-gt-oegwerP-ongarwbett-xiap.e-t-e--ifi--etti-e-h-o-op-ntis--min-htahtet-ntsorgheprn-biid,arg,excheetx-itnieenn-t-Pre-hev-cgngW-ttei,

Discover the method, decipher the text, and follow the directions hidden in it. Computerized solvers are helpful but not strictly required.

Hint:

> The method used here is similar to an existing method. Start by finding a partial solution.

Comment: Is there an use of ROT15 in certain layer of encryption???